# SyntaxError: Unexpected token D at Object.parse (native)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am uploading files using Spring Boot and Angular JS. My Java controller returns some details of a file such as the date, the type, the inputs of the form which are the name of the uploader and the file.

So when I click on `import Report`, I can upload the file, but I don't have the details added to the table. I have an empty row.

So what am  doing wrong?

Here's my form:

```html
 <section id="contact-info">

    <section id="contact-page">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="center">
                <p class="lead">Import reports</p>
            </div> 
            <div class="row contact-wrap"> 
                <div class="status alert alert-success" style="display: none"></div>
                <form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>name *</label>
                            <input type="text" name="NameOfUploader" class="form-control" required="required" ng-model="r.NameOfUploader">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>file</label>
                            <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" fileread="r.file">
                        </div>
```

My controller java

```java
public class DRController {
    @Autowired
    private DetailsReportRepository detailsReportRepository;
    @RequestMapping(value="/upload",headers=("content-type=multipart/*"),consumes = {"multipart/form-data"}, method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String  handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("NameOfUploader") String NameOfUploader,@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {

                DetailsReport d2=new DetailsReport();
                d2.setNameOfUploader(NameOfUploader);
                d2.setTypeOfFile(file.getContentType());
                d2.setDateOfUpload(new Date(new java.util.Date().getTime()));
                d2.setFile(convert(file));
                detailsReportRepository.save(d2);
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                BufferedOutputStream stream =
                        new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new  File("F:/FilesStore/" + d2.getId_file()+"-"+d2.getNameOfUploader())));
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();
                return d2.toString();
           } catch (Exception e) {
               System.err.print("erreur");
           }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public File convert(MultipartFile file)
    {    
        File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
        try {
            convFile.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile); 
            fos.write(file.getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return convFile; 
    }
}
```

My controller js

```js
//Upload files
$scope.upload = function() {
    var fd = new FormData();
    var url='http://localhost:8080/upload';
    fd.append("file", $scope.r.file);
    fd.append("NameOfUploader",$scope.r.NameOfUploader);
    $http.post(url,fd,{
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    })
    .success(function(data){
        var b=JSON.parse(data);
        $scope.reports.push(b); 

        console.log(Json.parse(data));

        console.log($scope.reports);
    })
    .error(function(){
    });
}



<div class="form-group">
    <a  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"  ng-click="upload()">Import File</a>
</div>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Id_file</th>
        <th>NameOfUploader</th>
        <th>DateOfUpload</th>
        <th>TypeOfFile</th>
        <th>File</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="r in reports">
        <td></td>
        <td>{{r.NameOfUploader}}</td>
        <td>{{r.DateOfUpload}}</td>
        <td>{{r.TypeOfFile}}</td>
        <td>{{r.file}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>   
</div>
```

Here's what I have:

[image]

Comment: Where is that console output of an array of objects coming from in the code above? also, `console.log(Json.parse(data));` should throw an error... typo?

Comment: I'am sorry  i don't understand what you mean !

Comment: Which part did you not understand so i can answer appropriately?

Comment: The first part , for the second why it should throws an error , i wanted just to see if the parse from string to json is done

Comment: for the first part, your image that the bottom i can see `[object, object, object, object, object]`, which is the result of a `console.log(something)`. i'm asking what console.log caused it.

Comment: as far as my second note, `Json` is undefined, you should instead be using `JSON.parse`

Comment: Okay for  the array of objects i think it's the result of the success(function) because i don't have any console.log(***) there.

Comment: It shouldn't be possible for the console.log to work AND for that error to occur, unless the error is coming from elsewhere. it's happening on **line 32** of **app.js**, what line is that?

Comment: It has nothing to do with this function .the line 32 is   : console.log($scope.dataTypes);   in this function $http.get("/getTypes")
   .success(function(data){
    $scope.dataTypes=data;
    console.log($scope.dataTypes);
   });

Comment: Then the error you are getting is originating from angular, and it's due to your server not returning valid json.

Comment: so what can i do , changing the return of  the string method to  json?

Comment: dunno, i don't know java.

Comment: Okay thank you  so much for your help i will try changing the type of the return

Comment: I resolve the problem by returning only d2 and deleting the parse from angular controlleur but i recuperate only the file in table .Can you tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just change the uppercase of your attributes

```
<tr ng-repeat="r in reports">
                        <td></td>
                        <td>{{r.nameOfUploader}}</td>
                        <td>{{r.dateOfUpload}}</td>
                        <td>{{r.typeOfFile}}</td>
                        <td>{{r.file}}</td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: Thank you it works , now i want to make a link to the file here in <td>{{r.file}}</td> , i don't know how to do it ?